# How to spot malwares that hide their disk usage from Resource monitor?

Tags: malware, windows, windows-10, rootkits

So lets say a malware has hid itself from task manager, so it wont show up in there.

lets also say that it also hides  its disk usage from resource monitor as well. (based on previously asked question this is possible, but correct me if I'm wrong)

then how to spot this? can popular Anti viruses detect this?

if not, then what should I do? is there any software that can also find disk  activities which are hidden in resource monitor? or is there any software that can find inconsistencies between resource-monitor and actual usage?

this question is based on a real life scenario I encountered which a HDD inside a computer was being used 100% based on the lights on the HDD itself and the sound it made, but there was no process using it inside the resource-monitor, how can we detect which process is using it in this scenario?

Comment: "a HDD inside a computer was being used 100% based on the lights on the HDD itself and the sound it made, but there was no process using it inside the resource-monitor" - Just because this is happening doesn't imo necessarily mean it's malware related. It's a symptom of potentially many causes.

Comment: Hello Mery Ted. If you believe that your machine might be infected with malware, it's often best to rescue really important documents, wipe the disk completely and re-install the operating system. I suggest using a live operating system booted via USB to save documents, as to reduce the chance of infecting a mass storage device (and thus infecting the new OS too).